# Value of integral at single point using definition of fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let's $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. By fundamental theorem of calculus we have:

$$
\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)} = \lim_{x \to b-}{F(x)} - \lim_{x \to a+}{F(x)}
$$

Where $F$ is primitive function of $f$ on $(a, b)$.

By Riemann definition of integral when a = b, then by definition holds: $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)} = 0$. Can we assume the same when we use definition of integral by fundamental theorem of calculus?

When $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to b-}{F(x)} = \lim_{x \to a+}{F(x)}$ is bounded, by fundamental theorem of calculus it naturally holds that: $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)} = 0$, what about the case when $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to b-}{F(x)} = \lim_{x \to a+}{F(x)} = \pm\infty$ ?

Thus applying definition of fundamental calculus when limits are unbounded, we get indeterminate expression.

Is this the right approach or by convention value of integral is always $0$?

Thanks.

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of calculus is proven when $a \neq b$. We can prove it by the intermediate value theorem for integrals and does not necessarily hold for when $a=b$ without the convention that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx=0$